# matrix multiplication without aggregation with cublasSgemm. How to?

Tags: cuda

Is it possible by calling cublasSgemm only or have to use cublasSscal for each row??

```
//  A[m * k]     B[k  * n]    
//  | 1   |    | 7 1 4 7 |    | 7  1  4  7|     
//  | 2   |  * | 8 2 5 8 | =  |16  4 10 16|
//  | 3   |    | 9 3 6 9 |    |27  9 18 27|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) or broadcasting in CUBLAS (or standard BLAS for that matter), and gemm cannot be used in the way you are asking.

Comment: [b]Thanks. What step to reproduce this functionality will be? This does not work too.[/b]
[code]
    float* iterMatrix = pDevMatrix3D;

    for( size_t index = 0; index < length; index++ )
    {
        cudaError_t status = ::cudaMemcpy( iterMatrix, pDevMatrix2D, height * width * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice );
        iterMatrix += height * width * (int)sizeof(float);
    }
    if( CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != ::cudaMemcpy( pMatrix3D, pDevMatrix3D, length * height * width * (int)sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) )
    {
        return -5;
    }[/code/

Comment: @user2347380 I suggest you accept this answer and ask another question.  It's not recommended to ask new questions in the comments area.  It's also difficult to read unformatted code in the comments.  Starting a new question will make it easier to read *and* to respond to specifically.